# In how many ways can the letters of ENGRAVER be arranged if vowels need to be separated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can the letters of ENGRAVER be arranged if vowels need to be separated?

There are $6$ spots the AEE can go into to get separated.

And there are $5$ ways to arrange the N,G,R,V,R $\to$ $5!/2!$.

For the AEE way, do I just do $6P3$ or $3!/2!$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider ENGRAVIS instead, so the consonants and vowels are distinct.

Now you can place four slots between the consonants and one at either side:
$$\rm
\_\ C_1\ \_\ C_2\ \_\ C_3\ \_\ C_4\ \_\ C_5\ \_
$$
This can be done in $5!$ ways.

You have to choose three out of the six slots to fill in the vowels, which can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. Once the choice is made, we can choose among $3!$ ways to fill in the vowels.

Now we take into account that S is actually R and I is actually E, so we have counted each placement four times, precisely $2!\cdot2!$.

Hence the total number is
$$
\frac{1}{2!\,2!}\cdot5!\cdot\binom{6}{3}\cdot3!
$$

Answer (score 0):

${6\choose3}\frac {5!}{2!}\frac {3!}{2!}$

The first factor is the arrangement of vowels and consonants.  The second is the arrangement of consonants, and the 3rd is the arrangement of vowels.

Answer (score 0):

First, we arrange the five consonants, then we insert the vowels.

*Arranging the five consonants*:  Choose two of the five positions for the $R$s, which can be done in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, then arrange the remaining three distinct consonants in the remaining three positions, which can be done in $3!$ ways.  Hence, the consonants can be arranged in
$$\binom{5}{2}3!$$
distinguishable ways.

As you can verify, this is equal to your answer
$$\frac{5!}{2!}$$
for the number of distinguishable arrangements of the consonants.

This creates six spaces, four between successive consonants and two at the ends of the row.  For instance,
$$\square R \square N \square G \square R \square V \square$$

*Inserting the vowels*:  To separate the three vowels, we must place them in three of these six spaces.  Choose two of the six spaces for the two $E$s and one of the remaining four spaces for the $A$.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$
distinguishable ways.

*Total*:  Since these choices can be made independently, the number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word $ENGRAVER$ in which no two vowels are adjacent is 
$$\binom{5}{2}3! \cdot \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$

*Why are your proposed answers for the number of arrangements of the vowels incorrect?*

The quantity $P(6, 3)$ is incorrect since the two $E$s are indistinguishable.  Notice that dividing $P(6, 3)$ by the $2!$ ways we could permute the $E$s within an arrangement without producing an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement yields
$$\frac{P(6, 3)}{2!} = \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$
The quantity $\frac{3!}{2!}$ is incorrect because you have not accounted for the $\binom{6}{3}$ ways you could place the two vowels.  Notice that 
$$\binom{6}{3} \cdot \frac{3!}{2!} = \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$